# Reading numbers from a chosen line in a file C++

Tags: c++

I want to know if I can read numbers from a chosen line in a file in c++.For example if I have .txt file like :

```
2 3
1 2 3 4
4 5 6 7
```

There are 3 lines, how can I read only the numbers on line 2 without having to read anything else?

Comment: why do you not want to read anything else? How would you know where the first line ends when you do not read it? The simple way is to read the first line and skip it, then read the next line

Comment: You can't. Just read and discard the lines you don't want.

Comment: If the lines have predictable lengths, you can calculate at which byte you should start reading. But in general, no. You cannot know at which line you are currently without reading everything before that byte.

Comment: @NO_NAME: The size of the line endings must also have a predictable length. For example, on Microsoft Windows, they have a length of 2 (`\r\n`), whereas on Linux, they have a length of 1 (`\n`). Therefore, any attempt to calculate a file offset yourself will probably not be portable. See my answer for further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you know the exact file offset of the second line from a previous call to [`std::istream::tellg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg), then you will have to read the first line in order to get to the position of the second line. You can use the function [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for reading the first line as a `std::string`, or you can use [`std::istream::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to read and discard the first line, like this:

```
input.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

If you do happen to know the exact offset of the second line, then you can call [`std::istream::seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) in order to directly jump to that offset.

Note, howevever, that a file offset does not necessarily correspond to the number of characters that you see when reading the file in text mode. For example, on different platforms, line endings may consist of a different number of characters, which get translated to the single character `\n` when reading the file in text mode. However, the file offset required by `std::istream::seekg` is the offset in binary mode. Therefore, you should generally not attempt to calculate such an offset yourself (unless you opened the stream in binary mode, which you should not do for text files). You should only use the function `std::istream::tellg` for obtaining such an offset.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file line by line in C++ using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    fstream newfile;
    newfile.open("file.txt",ios::in);
    if (newfile.is_open()){ 
        string tp;
        int i=0;
        while(getline(newfile, tp)){ 
            if (i==1) {
                cout << tp << endl; // this will only print the second line
            }
            i+=1;
         }
         newfile.close();
    }
}
```